# Start SQL Server jobs (say job 2 and job 4) after ensuring that the job1completed successfully

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, sql-job

I have SQL Server Agent jobs - Job 2 and Job 4 that need to run only after the database restore (Job 1) is completed.

Job 1 applies updates to the database and is critical and time consuming. So, I am not looking to add any other step in this job.

Job 2 and 3 are the table extracts that need to run only after job 1 is completed. In doing so, I do not want to re-run Job 1 given that Job 1 is time-consuming and has its own fixed schedule.

If possible, I would like to add a step in job 2 and job 3 and achieve this.
I would appreciate your insights on how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following query at the end of your query or you can add as a step so that it starts the other job

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'other_job_name'
```

Comment: I am looking for another way without tampering Job1. I did try this and was wondering if there is any other alternative.

Comment: Maybe, you can write a trigger to msdb..sysjobhistory table so that you can start the other job I never try it but you can check the following. https://mikesdatawork.wordpress.com/2015/07/15/create-a-trigger-on-the-sysjobhistory-table-to-execute-a-job/